# Live video streaming from one android device to another device

Tags: android, kotlin, video, video-streaming, streaming

As part of my new project I need to develop two android applications for video streaming. one app will select the video files from its storage space and starts to play them locally. At the same time the same video has to be played in another android device connected with the same WiFi.

I had used OpenCV android library for extracting the frames from video file(In Sender app) and planned to send this frames to another devices via OpenDDS library. But my doubt is that how can i play this video using the received frames in receiver app. Is it possible ? If not how can I achieve this functionality in android app. The requirement is to play lively not after receiving all frames.

Any suggestions or solutions...

Comment: This is a really broad question...  It isn't clear at all what your latency and quality requirements are, which will dictate the solution.  Low latency and low quality, check out WebRTC.  But if you're just playing video from storage... why not just stream the file?

Comment: Sorry if my question makes confusion... My intention is to play video in one app and at the same time without any latency or delay the same video has to be played in another device.

So my doubt is if I had sent the video file as frames to another device how it can be played in another device.